# GRPC C++ libraries accountability

Tags: grpc

When building the GRPC libraries from sources, for example on Android, I counter the following issues:

1. I have to remove libgrpc_unsecure and libgrpc++_unsecure in order
   for the initialization of GRPC not to get stuck.
2. I see that there are two libraries: libprotobuf and libprotobuf-lite.
   Which is the differences between them(other than the fact that
   probably the lite version contains less functions), which one I
   should include?
3. When generating the .so libraries it is generating also the .a
   libraries and if I use the .a libraries a function is not found, so I
   have to get back to using the .so, but in that case should I also use
   the .a? If not, is there a way to build just the .so?

Is there a link where it specifies the purpose of each library and what should be used? For example I don't think grpc++_reflection is of some use in my case, but how do I know what it contains without having to pass through every symbol in it? I need to better understand how to use the library files.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, libgrpc and libgrpc_unsecure are mutually exclusive. So you need to choose one as a dependency of your application.
2. Your interpretation is correct. lite version has less feature so you can try lite first and switch to the regular one if it doesn't fit. You may want to check this https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/file_lists.cmake to see what's available and what isn't in the lite.
3. It depends on how you built gRPC.

gRPC has a couple of libraries but `grpc++` is the one you want to link against. I don't think it has a comprehensive doc for what is for what so checking out https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt is the best thing you can do to understand what features those libraries provide.